# addArrangedSubview and UITAbleViewCell = infinite loop :/

Tags: swift, uitableview, nib

I'm trying to create one cell via different XIB. So naturally, I tried that :

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellChapter", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UniversalXIB

    if let subStackTitre = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("titreSection", owner: self, options: nil).first as? TitreXIB {
        cell.stackChapter.addArrangedSubview(subStackTitre)
        subStackTitre.titreOulet.text = "pouet n°\(indexPath.row)"
    }

    if let subStackIcones = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("iconesStack", owner: self, options: nil).first as? IconesXIB {
        cell.stackChapter.addArrangedSubview(subStackIcones)
    }

    if let photoChapterImage = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("photoAvecLegende", owner: self, options: nil).first as? PhotoAvecLegendeXIB {
        cell.stackChapter.addArrangedSubview(photoChapterImage)
    }
```

However, every time I scroll, it adds the nib again, on top of the previous ones. I'm pretty sure the addArrangedSubview is guilty here, but I have absolutely no clue of another method… The trick is, I'm also going to add this :

```
    for i in texteArray {
        let titreBool = i["titre"] as! Bool
        let photoBool = i["photo"] as! Bool

    if titreBool == true && photoBool == false {

    if let ChapitreTitre = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("chapitreTitre", owner: self, options: nil).first as? ChapitreTitre {
        cell.stackChapter.addArrangedSubview(ChapitreTitre)

    }

        } else if titreBool == false && photoBool == false {

    if let ChapitreSansTitre = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("chapitreSansTitre", owner: self, options: nil).first as? ChapitreSansTitre {
        cell.stackChapter.addArrangedSubview(ChapitreSansTitre)

    }

        } else if titreBool == true && photoBool == true {

    if let ChapitreTitrePhoto = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("chapitreTitrePhoto", owner: self, options: nil).first as? ChapitreTitrePhoto {
                cell.stackChapter.addArrangedSubview(ChapitreTitrePhoto)

    }

        } else if titreBool == false && photoBool == true {

        if let ChapitreSansTitrePhoto = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("chapitreSansTitrePhoto", owner: self, options: nil).first as? ChapitreSansTitrePhoto {
            cell.stackChapter.addArrangedSubview(ChapitreSansTitrePhoto)

            }
        }
    }
```

So if I've got 5 elements in my array, it would have to create 5 elements based on two bools. If I've got 2 thousands, it would create 2 thousans chapters.

Any idea on how to proceed ? Or what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Inside what function are these code blocks? `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: `addArrangedSubview` is for UIStackView, not UITableView. Could you post your UIStackView code as well?

Comment: Well there's no code attached to it, just an outlet. I didn't set up up the stack in the code, just with IB !

Comment: I'm starting to think that storing the added elements somewhere, like in a variable should be a good idea, so I can remove them at every cell loading, but how ?